# WSO2 Identity Server SAML SSO endpoint hard codes the AuthnContextClassRef

Tags: saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

In WSO2IS v4.6.0, the `AuthnContextClassRef` value is hardcoded to `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password`. In fact, the SAML SSO endpoint actually authenticates users via HTTPS by default and the `AuthnContextClassRef` value in this case should be `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport`.

What's the best way to correct this or get this issue on WSO2's radar?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a JIRA ticket for this issue: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-2585

While waiting for an offical fix, you can override their DefaultSAML2SSOManager by specifiing your own class in repository/conf/security/application-authentication.xml with:

Parameter name="SAML2SSOManager">my.version.of.SAML2SSOManager

I use a slightly modified version of their DefaultSAML2SSOManager and am able to connect to our IDP.